# Fill to end of sheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

So I am copying and pasting updated identification keys into column A on my spreadsheet.  Starting in column B there are formulas based on those keys that will update if the new keys are updated.  My problem is, if I have more keys than I had before, the formulas obviously won't populate in the cells adjacent to the new keys.  I thought of writing a macro to fill down the formulas in each specific column to the row where column A ends.  I know how to fill down but I am unsure how to have it do so up until the row where column A ends.  I am rather new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: search the web for auto fill, you dont need a macro there are hot keys.  In the name box if you put A1:A500 and hit enter then do a control-D it will auto fill down to cell A500

Comment: Don't just think of writing a macro, write the macro. ;) The key here is to understand exactly how many rows to fill. End of sheet is not good, you don't want 1 million formulas looking at you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it going to the last filled cell pasted and moving one cell to right, then you check if the cell is empty and if yes just select all up blank cells plus one with the formulas and fill down.